# How to get the Size of the Properties in groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am using SoapUI.

PassedValue might be "Open" or "Closed" or "Pending" or "Open,Closed". etc.

```
ExpectedValue = context.testCase.getPropertyValue("PassedValue")
```

I am trying to get the size of PassedValue but it is returning the number of characters as Size.. Can I get the actual size 1 when it has one string, and 2 if it has two strings..

How to convert `ExpectedValue` to Array and get the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use split e.g.

```
​def PassedValue = 'Open,Closed'​
assert 2 == PassedValue.split(',')?.size()​​​
```

Comment: I want get the size as 1 if it does not have separator.. will it work for that??